# How to separate task runner (Gulp - Grunt) source code from build code?

Tags: git, gruntjs, workflow, gulp, frontend

Imagine you are using something like Grunt or Gulp to improve your FE workflow. The file structure might look something like this.

```
 - workflow-project-folder
  - source
   - ...HTML/JS/CSS preprocess code...
  - .git
```

And your task runner is producing

```
 - workflow-project-folder
  - source
  - build
   - ...Complied code SASS to CSS etc....
  - .git
```

Maybe your (fictional) project looks like

```
- app/cms-project-folder
 - themes
    - assets
     - css
     - images
     - js
    - includes
    - templates
    index.pgmlang
 - system
 - libs
 - plugins
 - foo.pgmlang
 - bar.pgmlang
 .git
```

You have all that version controlled because you wanted to bootstrap your task runner and file structure, preprocess mixins and all. So you can't have it in the same git repo as the project without a messy codebase, so then there's this horrible disconnect between building tools and the project code. How do we manage this? Can it work under one repo? How would you for example put this into Wordpress, Drupal or another file structures with this seperation?

Some sub optimal solutions:

- Copy the build code over by hand, this is a one way solution (meaning you can't just make the code changing in the project and boom it's done). We have to remember to go back to the task runner project to change any code, then copy over again. Managing two repos.
- Clone the task runner repo into my project repo and somehow link the build code to the application theme. Meaning I have lots of bulk code in with my application that's just there to build it. Not a clean and could lead to other complications with core code etc.

There must be a better way of linking build code. Any ideas people?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I like to use Bower and NPM to manage the build dependencies. They'll use a `bower.json` file and a `package.json` file to specify the specific versions of your project's dependencies. Then, when you've just cloned your repository all you have to do is `bower install && npm install` before your Grunt build.

If you have a more customized set of dependencies you can include them via [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). In this case, you'd have your main repository which includes via a submodule a specific version of the a library repository.